# increase or decrease the height of imageView when scrolling up or down

Tags: swift, iphone, scrollview

increase or decrease the height of `imageView` when scrolling up or down

```
extension DetailViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


            if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    print("going down")
                    if self.imgViewHeight.constant >= 200 {
                        self.blurView.alpha = 0

                        self.backButton.isHidden = false
                    }
                    else if self.imgViewHeight.constant <= 200{
                        self.blurView.alpha = 1


                        self.imgViewHeight.constant = self.imgViewHeight.constant + 4

                    }
                }, completion: nil)

            }
            else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    if self.imgViewHeight.constant <= 72 {
                       self.blurView.alpha = 1
                        self.backButton.isHidden = false
                        self.descriptions.isScrollEnabled = true
                    }
                    else if self.imgViewHeight.constant >= 72{
                        self.blurView.alpha = 1

                        self.imgViewHeight.constant = self.imgViewHeight.constant - 4

                    }

                    print("lolol:\(self.imgViewHeight.constant)")

                }, completion: nil)

            }
            else {

            }

            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
}
```

Comment: if you will see pokemon guide detail screen i want it like that. thank for help

Comment: parallax scrolling?

Comment: no normal scroll

Answer (score 0):

you can use ScrollView functions such as:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
//your code when you want start scrolling

}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
//your code when you want run after stop scrolling

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for Ans but i am already using that. i am sure i am doing some idiotic mistake in logic

Comment: try this way:
make outlet from your scroll view Height and put your code inside
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **`layoutIfNeeded()`** on `view` in the `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)` `animations closure` after setting the `imgViewHeight.constant` value.

```
extension DetailViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {[weak self] in
                self?.imgViewHeight.constant = 20 //This is just an example
                self?.view.layoutIfNeeded() //Here..........
            }
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {[weak self] in
                self?.imgViewHeight.constant = 0 //This is just an example
                self?.view.layoutIfNeeded() //Here..........
            }
        }
        //Rest of the code...
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've used sample values of `height constraint (20 and 0)`. Add your own logic of `height` there instead.